# Is there a way to remap the inventory hotkeys in Warcraft 3?

Tags: warcraft-3

Warcraft 3 (and it's expansion The Frozen Throne) has a pretty extensive hotkey customization feature. However I can't seem to find a way to customize the hotkeys for my inventory items.

The inventory hotkeys are default set to numpad 7,8,6,5,1, and 2. With each number corresponding to a particular slot in your 6 block inventory.

My labtop sadly does not boast a numpad, so as of right now I have no way to activate my inventory items short of clicking them manually, which becomes a real game changer when I'm playing DotA and every half-second actually matters in heated combat.

Does anybody know of any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://dotacustomkeys.com/generator.php) you can set your hero skills to custom keys,it also has the option to set the inventory to custom keys(under "**Extensions (Win Only)**" tab).

Note that setting the inventory keys will require you to download additional script...the site has the guide for that so try it out.

[This](http://warkeys.sourceforge.net/) is your second option,I didn't tried it so i cant tell you much.

Comment: this seems like its going to work like a charm. I've just about finished configuring all my settings. After I test it out, if it works, you'll get your check. +1 for now. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

While your laptop may not have a number pad there should be a way that you can turn on a lock that turns on a pseudo numberpad on the right side of your keyboard. Generally it turns 789 = 789, uio = 456, jkl = 123. You should see these numbers on these keys.

Other designs have it where you press Fn+key to get the keypad number. For example, Fn+i = Keypad 5.

Comment: not with this labtop, but +1 because its an excellent idea that would normally have worked.

Comment: :( Well that's truly unfortunate. Almost all laptops I've encountered have had this functionality. Sucks that your's doesn't.

Comment: yea i know, this labtop is kinda crappy. the freaking cpu fan went like 2months after i bought it, its keyboard is more than subpar for several reasons, and its wireless is rather weak. meh. it was cheap. lol